# Python: Using a list to execute arguements

Tags: python

Sorry if this is basic question I'm new to python and i couldn't find the proper way to do this within the api docs.

I have a list that contains stack arguments in the fashion

[push,3][push,2][push,1][pop][add]... so on

I also have a StackMachine.py file that created a class Stack:with the member functions push pop add sub mul div mod

I imported it into my main.py file and i want to go through my list and execute the arguments using the functions i made in my StackMachine.py file.

My question is how to analyze the list and use my member functions from the Stack class.

my main.py looks like

```
from StackMachine import Stack
import sys
toks = []
f = open(sys.argv[1])
for line in f.readlines():
  tokens = line.split()
  toks.append(tokens)
f.close()
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because it's riddled with trivial errors. You really need to talk to an instructor, because these are really basic issues; you're comparing the function `type` to `tuple` (never true), you're calling methods on a class, not an instance of a class, you're name shadowing built-ins (never name a variable `list`), etc. And you haven't provided the `Stack` code so we can't even be sure it's supposed to be used the way you're using it. This is a giant cluster of problems, pointing them out one by one won't really solve anything; the problem is not understanding Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not work because one you forgot the colon after the if statement, `if i == "push":` and `if i == "pop":`. For the push, 1 and push, 2 part you would be checking a tuple which is a data structure that is similar to a list but is immutable. So to check what the number is or what the first argument is you would do `if i[0] == "push" and i[1] == 1:` but before this if statement you would have to check if that object is a tuple so you would do `if type = tuple:`